# Как пропустить создание модели в форме? django

Tags: python, django

это модель с телефонами

**models**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone format: '+999999999'")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], unique=True, max_length=17)
```

есть форма

**forms**

```
class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneInputField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(RelatedAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone'].choices = Clients.objects.order_by('-phone').values_list('phone')
        self.fields['phone'].label = 'Телефон'

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['phone']
        widgets = {
        }
```

При сохранении, надо, если человек указал поле телефона пустым, просто не создавать эту модель. Как это сделать? Пробовал через clean, не получилось. Я так понимаю проблема в RegexValidator?

на сайте несколько форм подряд идут из разных приложений и если эта форма пустая просто как бы пропускать ее, а не стопорить другие формы

Answer (score 0):

В классе Clients(или том, который вам нужен) можно попробовать переопределить метод save() при условии

```
if self.phone
    def save (*args, **kwargs):
```

В теле вызываете метод super
Должно помочь, я просто не могу оставлять комментарии(